# Why does no three-scalar parameterization of 3d orientation exist that doesn't contain singularities?

Tags: resource-recommendations, mathematics

I'm reading a magazine [article](https://www.chrishecker.com/images/b/bb/Gdmphys4.pdf) on 3d orientation and want to know what the mathematical issue is and where to read about it, preferably a theorem title that I can google or a topic and textbook:

> It’s possible to prove that no three-scalar parameterization of 3D
>   orientation exists that doesn’t suck, for some suitably mathematically
>   rigorous definition of “suck.” I haven’t done this proof (I think it
>   uses some pretty high-end group theory, which I haven’t learned yet),
>   so I can’t tell you exactly how it works, but I believe the gist of
>   the proof is that no minimal parameterization exists that doesn’t
>   contain singularities. These singularities can take different forms —
>   depending on how you allocate the three degrees of freedom — but
>   according to the math, it’s impossible to get rid of them.

Comment: This is a nice question, but it seems like it's pure math. (It is addressed in Math.SE, under a slightly different context, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210408/embedding-compact-boundaryless-n-manifolds-in-n-dimensional-real-space).)